# Object Array Declaration in Groovy

Tags: groovy

How come I cannot declare an array of `People` in Groovy as shown.
Maybe I'm lacking the deeper understanding of classes

```
class People {
    Integer id
}

class Job {
    def func() {
        People[] p = new People[10]
    }
}
```

I get an error of People[] cannot be applied to app.People[]

Comment: Unfortunately that is just the nature of the language it looks like...
in order to allocate an object that is not on the stack, (Or it's size is predeterministic) -- you must use the def keyword

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code sample you have shown does not reproduce the error you mentioned in the question above. It's broken actually and does not compile - method `func()` is missing its body. If you correct the code to e.g.

```
class People {
    Integer id
}

class Job {
    def func() {
        People[] p = new People[10]
        assert p.size() == 10
        println p
    }
}

new Job().func()​
```

you will see it produces the expected result - check it out in the Groovy web console [here](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/edit/5154073565200384). When you run it you will see following output to the console:

```
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

#### The difference between Groovy and Java

When it comes to array initialization there is one significant difference between Groovy and Java. In Java you can initialize an array of `People[]` like this:

```
People[] p = new People[] { new People(), new People(), /* ... */ new People() };
```

It wont work in Groovy, because Groovy reserves `{}` for closures. In Groovy you can initialize such array as:

```
People[] p = [new People(), new People(), new People()] as People[]
```

Comment: Hmm I did have brackets in my code, just didn't include in the question. Thanks for the clarification though!

Answer (score 2):

While Szymon Stepniak's answer is correct for Groovy 2.5 and below, Java-style array initialization are part of the enhancements of Groovy 3.0 and 2.6 made possible by the new parrot parser.

Example from the [release notes](http://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-3.0.html):

```
def primes = new int[] {2, 3, 5, 7, 11}
assert primes.size() == 5 && primes.sum() == 28
assert primes.class.name == '[I'

def pets = new String[] {'cat', 'dog'}
assert pets.size() == 2 && pets.sum() == 'catdog'
assert pets.class.name == '[Ljava.lang.String;'

// traditional Groovy alternative still supported
String[] groovyBooks = [ 'Groovy in Action', 'Making Java Groovy' ]
assert groovyBooks.every{ it.contains('Groovy') }
```

Answer (score 0):

Szymon Stepniak's answer is correct. I'll point another example of a real case  in some unit test that I've worked (general Object type):

```
Object[] o = [YourModel] as Object[]
```

This is sufficient to mock a general Object with your model properties.